# RAID and corrupted installation of Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I have problem with installing Windows 10 when RAID is enabled. I thing, that when RAID is enabled, some installed files are corrupted. I have:

- ASUS ROG STRIX X399
- Samsung Evo 860 500GB
- 2x WD blue 1TB

First, I set up RAID that SSH disk was Volume, and two HDD where RAID 1. After installing Windows 10 on SSD, some files where missing (when I tried installing AURA Sync, I got error that InstallShield Kernel was not found. I check integrity of files in windows (DISM and SFC tools) and it look ok, so I did repair reinstall of system, but problem still occurred.

Then I change RAID configuration of SSD disk to RAIDABLE,set Read/Write Policy to cache and reinstall Windows from scratch - problem still occurred. Then I set Read/Write Policy of SSD disk to not caching, and fresh reinstall of Windows - still the same problem.

Then I removed RAID configuration and set SATA to AHCI, reinstall Windows and InstallShield works correctly.

All operations I did on the newest BIOS version (0808) and RAID driver (AMD RAID device driver V9.2.0.87).

Hard to say, put probably there is something with RAID configuration, because four fresh installing of Windows had problems when RAID was enable. Without RAID, it work on first try.

As it was fresh install I only figured out that there is problem with InstallShield, but I can assume that some other files are also corrupted.

Any ideas what can I try to resolve above problem? 
Software RAID is not solution for me, because I plan to have dual boot with Windows and Linux, where both will use disks with RAID configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, it was wrong order of installing RAID drivers during Windows Setup. First I loaded drivers as they were if alphabetic order:

1. RAID Bottom
2. RAID Config
3. RAID Driver

When I changed order to:

1. RAID Bottom
2. RAID Driver
3. RAID Config

Everything work as expected.